# C# - Test that all calls to .Single(), .First(), etc. conform to coding standards

Tags: c#, code-analysis, xunit, xunit.net, roslyn-code-analysis

We use some extension methods, which allows us to write something like:

```
.Single(e => $"{nameof(SomeParameter)}: {SomeParameter}, ...")
```

instead of just

```
.Single()
```

where `e` is an exception.

This **greatly** increases logging experience because the upper variant logs all parameters instead of useless "Sequence contains no elements", which the bottom one produces.

I need to write a test, which would find all non-compliant code, e.g. calls to `.Single()`.

Sure, I can use a regex search or just a plain vanilla text search to look in all CS files starting from the solution root and *maybe* this is the way to go. I just wonder if there is already a simple and known solution for that.

Here is what I need:

1. Easily add / remove rules: e.g. find all files, which have `.Single()`, find all which have `.Single(` but which is not in the form of `.Single(e => $"` - this is to account for a combined Where + Single code, etc...
2. The test(s) should run from xUnit.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're looking for a Roslyn analyzer, which would run as part of the build, not from xUnit.

Comment: @SLaks Great, thanks. Googling is with us and it will produce the result within a reasonable amount of time. Would you be able to narrow down the "direction", e.g. provide relevant references, examples, etc? That would qualify as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write a Roslyn analyzer, which will run as part of your build (and as you type in Visual Studio) and give compilation errors (or warnings) as you like.

The analyzer has full access to the syntax tree and semantic model as generated within the compiler, and can check for accesses to specific methods.

[Getting Started](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-Writing-a-Custom-Analyzer-&-Code-Fix)